# adb shell screencap return black image from video

Tags: android, adb, screen-capture

I am trying to get a screenshot of a video on android 9 using standard command:

```
adb shell screencap -p /sdcard/printscreen.png
```

That works fine with any static content but just returns a black picture when trying to get screenshot of a video. I have seen quite a few similar questions, however do not seem to find an answer. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue seems to come from OpenGL. I have it working with:

1 - Open VLC on Android device
2 - Goto: Other => Settings
3 - Goto: Advanced => OpenGL ES2 usage
4 - Select "Force On"
5 - Back up one level, and select "Quit and restart application"

Alternatively, add the following line to data/data/org.videolan.vlc/shared_prefs/org.videolan.vlc_preferences.xml

```
<string name="opengl">1</string>
```

Now, the following command should work

```
adb shell screencap /sdcard/printscreen.png
```